# How to find any english letters in a excel cell?

Tags: excel, filter, excel-formula

In a cell contain english letters as well as other language letters as well.
Can anyone help me find the cells in a column which contain any English letters in MS Excel.

For eg: (RÃ. യൂണിയനിലെ 1950 സ്ഥാപനങ്ങൾ)
In the aboce cell contain both english and malayalam letters. I need to get filter those cells in ms excel.

There are several cells contain numbers,english letters, Malayalam letters and special symbols etc.  So I need to filter those cells which contain only english letters.

Comment: your question title is asking for English characters, but then the body says you want to find other letters - can you clarify what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Find(), match(), substitute() all possible but depends what you want. There are many questions asking and answers showing different methods on here. Worth a search.

Comment: There are several cells contain only Malayalam letters. At the same time there are some cells which contains with malayalam as well as english. So I need to filter those cells which contain english letters in malayalam content.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Modified the question